# How to measure a vehicles wheel bolt pattern?

Tags: wheels, measurement

How can I accurately measure a vehicles wheel bolt pattern, regardless if it is a car or truck?

- Are any special tools needed?
- Is there a certain process to measuring a pattern?

Answer (score 4):

PCD or Pitch Circle Diameter is typically given as a number multiplied by another number.  The first number is the number of bolts, nuts or studs and these can be simply counted.  The second number is the diameter of a circle which has a central point in the centre of the hub and whose outside line goes through the centre of each bolt hole.

It is therefore possible, using a simple ruler, to calculate the PCD using little more than a ruler and the conversion tables shown at [this](http://www.westerntowing.co.uk/acatalog/PCD_Calculation.html) useful link.

Comment: Steve, if you would, post the pic from your link then explain the math ... IOW, *bring the information here!* ... Great find, btw. I didn't realize there was a way you could find the PCD mathematically, but it perfect sense now that I think about it.